# Custom label for references using tasks inside a xsim exercise

Tags: cross-referencing, cleveref, tasks, ref, xsim

In order to create an assignment sheet, I am using the `xsim` package and to create subquestions within a question, I use the package `tasks`. The problem comes while referring to the subquestions. Ideally I would like the subquestions to be referred to as 1.2 or 1.3, instead they gets referred as just 1 as the MWE demonstrates. As you can see the output is really *stupid*.

I have these concerns

1. How do I get `cref` identify the subquestions as "subquestion 1.1".? I would ideally like to issue a directive something like `\crefname{subquestion}{subquestion}{subquestions}`. The `cref` invocation should also be able to distinguish between a mere question and a subquestion.
2. Suppose in future, I change `counter-format = tsk[1]` to
   `counter-format = tsk[r]`, would I get consistent output?
   Something like "subquestion 1.a"?

EDIT by magguu :: please see my half-working answer and corresponding MWE

Please see the MWE::

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tasks,cleveref,xsim}

\NewTasks[counter-format = tsk[1]),
    label-format = \itshape,%
    item-indent = 0em,%
    label-offset=0.8em,%
    label-align=left,%
    before-skip = 0pt,%
    after-item-skip=0pt%
]{subquestionblock}[\subquestion](2)

\crefname{exercise}{question}{questions}
\crefname{subquestion}{subquestion}{subquestions} % has no effect, obviously

\begin{document}
    \begin{exercise}[points=3]
        Isomers of a coordination compound. \label{iso}
        \begin{subquestionblock}
            \subquestion! Why do we have isomers? \label{why}
            \subquestion! Why did I even ask \cref{iso}? \label{metawhy}
            \subquestion! What do you mean \cref{metawhy}?
        \end{subquestionblock}
    \end{exercise}

    \begin{exercise}[points=3]
        Is there an end to stupid questions? \label{stu}
        \begin{subquestionblock}
            \subquestion! Discuss why \cref{metawhy} is a stupid question but \cref{why} is even stupider? \label{huh}
            \subquestion! Are both \cref{huh} and \cref{metawhy} both stupider that each other?
        \end{subquestionblock}
    \end{exercise}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Address your request to the author of the tasks-package and make a bug report:

1. The code of the tasks package comes without properly commented sources, just as a .sty-file and thus is inscrutable. Same for some of the packages loaded/used by the tasks-package.
2. It seems that instead of using `\refstepcounter`, the author of that package does his own counter-thingies, based on expl3 and using yet another one of his packages, called `cntformats`, which one has to spend hours on studying for finding out what might probably go on. According to my opinion, all this makes things even more inscrutable and, according to my opinion, is definitely not a good idea if one wishes ones own things to properly interact with common LaTeX2e-infrastructure.
3. Within that inscrutable package, `\cs_gset:Npx` is used for defining the macro `\@currentlabel`.  Seems this does redefine `\@currentlabel` globally. The LaTeX2e-kernel does never redefine `\@currentlabel` globally. If you do so, placing labels after ending one of those `tasks`-environments will yield wrong numbers when referencing these labels.

   (Well, the `hyperref`-package does redefine `\@currentHref` globally, which in my opinion is a similar well-established mis-concept as it may lead to connecting references with hyperlinks to wrong targets.)

   This sort of things does confuse and scare off those LaTeX-beginners who exercise the care of checking the correctness of the result while not being experienced enough for tracking down what is happening when things do not turn out correct. I saw users despairing after spending hours and days on studying inscrutable code instead of learning the relevant basics of their field of study as they were, while not yet knowing anything about these things, urged by teachers, who found another way of living out their profile neurosis, to use LaTeX and specific packages, which altogether they would never ever need again after leaving school/university.
4. You additionally use the package `cleveref`. This package does redefine some of the kernel-macros, e.g., `\refstepcounter` and does rely on people using standard-infrastructure for doing counter-thingies, which the `tasks`-package does not:

   `cleveref` does redefine `\refstepcounter` to also define an additional macro `\cref@currentlabel` and does redefine `\label` to write two `\newlabel`-entries to the .aux-file instead of one: The usual `\newlabel`-entry whose data stems from `\@currentlabel` and an additional `\newlabel`-entry where the label-name has the suffix `@cref` and whose data stems from `\cref@currentlabel` and which delivers the data needed additionally by the `cleveref`-referencing-macros.

   The `tasks`-package, which does its own counter-thingies and which does redefine `\@currentlabel` on its own instead of using LaTeX2e-infrastructure/`\refstepcounter`, does not set `\cref@currentlabel` and thus breaks, e.g., the  `cleveref` package.

---

Inspired by [your own answer/your hack](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/449215/118714) I just came up with a variant where you get rid of the closing parenthese and which makes `\cref` possible also and which also works out when using the **hyperref** package.

Of course my variant does not resolve the **tasks** package's behavior of redefining `\@currentlabel` globally but does the same thing for **cleveref**'s `\cref@currentlabel`.

The gist is:

I added another key "ugly-label-hook" to the tasks-package which lets you specify some tokens that get inserted whenever the tasks-package for one of its items modifies `\@currentlabel`.

You can use this hook for "refstepping" the "dummy"-counter for your subquestions/subanswers.

"refstepping" the "dummy"-counter makes sure the macros `\@currentlabel` and `\cref@currentlabel` are (re)defined correctly.

As the tasks-package does for whatever reason redefine `\@currentlabel` globally, with the "ugly-label-hook" it must be ensured that both `\@currentlabel` and `\cref@currentlabel` are (re)defined globally also.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tasks,cleveref,xsim}

% ====Begin of patch of tasks.sty====
\makeatletter
\ExplSyntaxOn

% Allocate another token list for the ugly hack:
\tl_new:N     \l__sillyugly_label_hook_tl

% Add a key "ugly-label-hook" for setting that
% token list:
\keys_define:nn {tasks/list}
  {
    ugly-label-hook    .tl_set:N   =  \l__sillyugly_label_hook_tl ,
  }

% Include the ugly-label-hook-key into the `tasks' object:
%   #1: number of items
%   #2: number of columns
%   #3: label-format
\DeclareObjectType {tasks} {3}
% the `default' template interface:
\DeclareTemplateInterface {tasks} {default} {3}
  {
    enumerate       : boolean   = true    ,
    label           : tokenlist           ,
    indent          : length    = 2.5em   ,
    counter-format  : tokenlist = tsk[a]) ,
    label-format    : tokenlist ,
    %----------------------------------------------------
    ugly-label-hook : tokenlist ,
    %----------------------------------------------------
    label-width     : length    = 1em     ,
    label-offset    : length    = .3333em ,
    item-format     : tokenlist ,
    after-item-skip : skip      = 1ex plus 1ex minus 1ex
  }

% When patching the next macro, the really unlikely marker $ with
% unusual catcode is used in ``$tasks$default$label$'':
\cs_set:Nx \__tasks_restore_dollar:
  { \char_set_catcode:nn {36} { \char_value_catcode:n {36} } }
\char_set_catcode_alignment:N \$

% Include the ugly-label-hook-key into the `default' template code
% and apply the hook when \@currentlabel is changed:
\DeclareTemplateCode {tasks} {default} {3}
  {
    enumerate          = \l__tasks_enumerate_bool           ,
    label              = \l__tasks_label_tl                 ,
    indent             = \l__tasks_item_default_indent_dim  ,
    counter-format     = \l__tasks_label_pattern_tl         ,
    label-format       = \l__tasks_label_format_tl          ,
    %----------------------------------------------------
    ugly-label-hook    = \l__sillyugly_label_hook_tl     ,
    %----------------------------------------------------
    label-width        = \l__tasks_label_default_width_dim  ,
    label-offset       = \l__tasks_label_default_offset_dim ,
    item-format        = \l__tasks_item_format_tl           ,
    after-item-skip    = \l__tasks_after_item_skip
  }
  {
    \AssignTemplateKeys
    \bool_if:NF \l__tasks_label_width_bool
      {
        \dim_set_eq:NN
          \l__tasks_label_width_dim
          \l__tasks_label_default_width_dim
      }
    \bool_if:NF \l__tasks_item_indent_bool
      {
        \dim_set_eq:NN
          \l__tasks_item_indent_dim
          \l__tasks_item_default_indent_dim
      }
    \bool_if:NF \l__tasks_label_offset_bool
      {
        \dim_set_eq:NN
          \l__tasks_label_offset_dim
          \l__tasks_label_default_offset_dim
      }
    % \dim_compare:nNnT
    %   { \l__tasks_item_indent_dim }
    %    <
    %   { \l__tasks_label_offset_dim + \l__tasks_label_width_dim }
    %   {
    %     \dim_set:Nn \l__tasks_item_indent_dim
    %       { \l__tasks_label_offset_dim + \l__tasks_label_width_dim }
    %   }
    \bool_if:NT \l__tasks_custom_after_item_skip_bool
      {
        \skip_set_eq:NN
          \l__tasks_after_item_skip
          \l__tasks_custom_after_item_skip
      }
    \bool_if:NT \l__tasks_custom_label_bool
      {
        \tl_set_eq:NN
          \l__tasks_label_tl
          \l__tasks_custom_label_tl
        \bool_set_false:N \l__tasks_enumerate_bool
      }
    \__tasks_label_align:V \l__tasks_label_align_tl
    % need this for enumerate list:
    \bool_if:nT { !\l__tasks_resume_bool && \l__tasks_enumerate_bool }
      { \int_gzero:N \g__tasks_int }
    \int_set:Nn \l__tasks_columns_int {#2}
    % set all the items in their own coffins and join with the ground:
    \int_gzero:N \g__tasks_current_col_num_int
    \int_set:Nn \g__tasks_current_row_num_int {1}
    \tl_if_blank:VF \l__tasks_custom_label_pattern_tl
      {
        \tl_set_eq:NN
          \l__tasks_label_pattern_tl
          \l__tasks_custom_label_pattern_tl
      }
    \tl_if_blank:VF \l__tasks_custom_label_format_tl
      {
        \tl_set_eq:NN
          \l__tasks_label_format_tl
          \l__tasks_custom_label_format_tl
      }
    \tl_if_blank:VF \l__tasks_custom_item_format_tl
      {
        \tl_set_eq:NN
          \l__tasks_item_format_tl
          \l__tasks_custom_item_format_tl
      }
    \seq_map_inline:Nn \l__tasks_seq
      {
        \__tasks_read_item:www ##1 \q_stop
        \bool_if:NTF \l__tasks_enumerate_bool
          {
            \tl_if_eq:VnT \l__tasks_tmp_label_tl { $tasks$default$label$ }
              {
                \int_gincr:N \g__tasks_int
                \SaveCounterPatternFrom [tasks]
                  \l__tasks_tmpa_tl
                  \l__tasks_label_tl
                  \l__tasks_label_pattern_tl
                %-----------------------------------------------------------
                % This seems to set \@currentlabel globally:
                %-----------------------------------------------------------
                \cs_gset:Npx \@currentlabel { \l__tasks_label_tl }
                %-----------------------------------------------------------
                % Carry out the ugly hook hack after setting \@currentlabel
                % for setting \@currentlabel correctly.
                % Seems with this package this needs to be done globally,
                % thus \uglycounterhack does it globally as well.
                %-----------------------------------------------------------
                \l__sillyugly_label_hook_tl
              }
          }
          {
            \tl_if_blank:VT \l__tasks_label_tl
              { \tl_set_eq:NN \l__tasks_label_tl \labelitemi }
          }
        \tl_put_left:NV \l__tasks_label_tl \l__tasks_label_format_tl
        % \tl_put_left:NV \l__tasks_item_tl \l__tasks_item_format_tl
        \tl_if_eq:VnTF \l__tasks_tmp_label_tl { $tasks$default$label$ }
          {
            \__tasks_task:VVV
              \l__tasks_label_tl
              \l__tasks_item_format_tl
              \l__tasks_item_tl
          }
          {
            \__tasks_task:VVV
              \l__tasks_tmp_label_tl
              \l__tasks_item_format_tl
              \l__tasks_item_tl
            \tl_clear:N \l__tasks_tmp_label_tl
          }
      }
  }

\__tasks_restore_dollar:

\ExplSyntaxOff
\makeatother

% ====End of patch of tasks.sty====

\DeclareExerciseTranslations{answer}{
  Fallback = answer ,
  English = answer ,
  French = r\'eponse ,
  German = Antwort
}


\DeclareExerciseType{question}{
  exercise-env = question ,
  solution-env = answer ,
  exercise-name = \XSIMtranslate{question} ,
  solution-name = \XSIMtranslate{answer} ,
  exercise-template = default ,
  solution-template = default
}

\newcounter{subquestion}[question]
\newcounter{subanswer}[answer]

\renewcommand*\thesubquestion{\thequestion.\arabic{subquestion}}%
\csname @ifpackageloaded\endcsname{hyperref}{%
  \renewcommand*\theHsubquestion{\theHquestion.\arabic{subquestion}}%
}%

\renewcommand*\thesubanswer{\theanswer.\arabic{subanswer}}%
\csname @ifpackageloaded\endcsname{hyperref}{%
  \renewcommand*\theHsubanswer{\theHanswer.\arabic{subanswer}}%
}%


% cleveref-aliases/counter-naming-phrases:
\crefname{question}{question}{questions}
\crefname{subquestion}{subquestion}{subquestions} % has no effect, obviously

\crefname{answer}{answer}{answers}
\crefname{subanswer}{subanswer}{subanswers} % has no effect, obviously

\makeatletter
% Why does the tasks-package its own counter-thingie when
% you have to use a counter anyway for getting things 
% with label..ref done correctly? This does not make sense to me.
\DeclareRobustCommand\uglycounterhack[1]{%
  \refstepcounter{#1}%
  \global\let\@currentlabel=\@currentlabel
  \global\let\cref@currentlabel=\cref@currentlabel
}%
\makeatother

\NewTasks[%
    %% This will not include the value of the question-counter
    %% into the subquestion-items:
    %%   counter-format = tsk[1]),%
    %% This will include the value of the question-counter
    %% into the subquestion-items -- I recommend doing this for making
    %% references to subquestion-items unambiguous:
    counter-format = \thequestion.tsk[1]),%
    label-format = \itshape,%
    ugly-label-hook = \uglycounterhack{subquestion},%
    label-width = 1.75em,%
    item-indent = 2.55em,%
    label-offset=0.8em,%
    label-align=left,%
    before-skip = 0pt,%
    after-item-skip=0pt%
]{subquestionblock}[\subquestion](2)

\NewTasks[%
    %% This will not include the value of the answer-counter
    %% into the subanswer-items:
    %%   counter-format = tsk[1]),%
    %% This will include the value of the answer-counter
    %% into the subanswer-items -- I recommend doing this for making
    %% references to subanswer-items unambiguous:
    counter-format = \theanswer.tsk[1]),%
    label-format = \itshape,%
    ugly-label-hook = \uglycounterhack{subanswer},%
    label-width = 1.75em,%
    item-indent = 2.55em,%
    label-offset=0.8em,%
    label-align=left,%
    before-skip = 0pt,%
    after-item-skip=0pt%
]{subanswerblock}[\subanswer](2)

\begin{document}
    \begin{question}[points=3]
        Isomers of a coordination compound. \label{iso}
        \begin{subquestionblock}
            \subquestion! Why do we have isomers? \label{why}
            \subquestion! Why did I even ask \cref{iso}? \label{metawhy}
            \subquestion! What do you mean \cref{metawhy}?
        \end{subquestionblock}
    \end{question}
    \begin{answer}[print=true]
        \begin{subanswerblock}
            \subanswer! Because isomers are fun. \label{because}
            \subanswer! Because I am funny. \label{metabecause}
            \subanswer! \cref{metabecause} is funny but all in all this is no longer funny. 
        \end{subanswerblock}
    \end{answer}

    \begin{question}[points=3]
        Is there an end to stupid questions? \label{stu}
        \begin{subquestionblock}
            \subquestion! Discuss why \cref{metawhy} is a stupid question but \cref{why} is even stupider? \label{huh}
            \subquestion! Are both \cref{huh} and \cref{metawhy} both stupider that each other?
        \end{subquestionblock}
    \end{question}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: hmmm ... this was lot more complicated than I thought. I really liked the packages ``tasks`` and ``cleveref``. Thanks for all the effort that you put into helping me out @Ulrich .. I have also written a mail to the package authors.

Answer (score 2):

After trying several things, now I have an ugly hack. It does not solve every thing and introduces some other irritants but it does solve the most vexing counter issue. For this I embed `exercise` in a new environment `question` which has its own counter called `question`. Then the formatting code of `subquestion` has a hack to increment another counter called `subquestion`.

The end result is that my concern number 2 gets resolved automatically as you can see in the output image attached : the subquestion 3.1 and subquestion 3.3.

However I still cannot resolve concern number 1. I tried to use some other hacks but got embroiled in `\expandafter` mess. I am not posting those efforts in my MWE here.

Now I have these new concerns:

3. How do I get rid of the ")" coming after every references?
4. How do I change several invocations of "question" to "subquestion". To wit, "question" in 1.2 should remain unchanged but other "question"s shd change to "subquestion". I could have changed definition of `\refsubq` but that would have other problems.

Please see the new MWE::

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tasks,cleveref,xsim}

\newcommand{\refsubq}[1]{\cref{#1}.\ref{#1}}
\newcounter{question}
\newcounter{subquestion}[question]
\newcommand{\uglyhack}{\refstepcounter{subquestion}\itshape}

\NewTasks[counter-format = tsk[1]),
    label-format = \uglyhack,%
    item-indent = 0em,%
    label-offset=0.8em,%
    label-align=left,%
    before-skip = 0pt,%
    after-item-skip=0pt%
]{subquestionblock}[\subquestion](2)

\NewTasks[counter-format = tsk[a]),
    label-format = \uglyhack,%
    item-indent = 0em,%
    label-offset=0.8em,%
    label-align=left,%
    before-skip = 0pt,%
    after-item-skip=0pt%
]{subquestionblockA}[\subquestion](2)

\newenvironment{question}{\refstepcounter{question}\exercise}{\endexercise}
\crefname{exercise}{question}{questions}

\crefname{subquestion}{subquestion}{subquestions} % has no effect, obviously
\crefname{subquestionblock}{subquestion}{subquestions} % fails
\crefname{subquestionblockA}{subquestion}{subquestions} % fails

\begin{document}
    \begin{question}
        Isomers of a coordination compound. \label{iso}
        \begin{subquestionblock}
            \subquestion! Why do we have isomers? \label{why}
            \subquestion! Why did I even ask \cref{iso}? \label{metawhy}
            \subquestion! What do you mean \refsubq{metawhy}?
        \end{subquestionblock}
    \end{question}

    \begin{question}
        Is there an end to stupid questions? \label{stu}
        \begin{subquestionblockA}
            \subquestion! Discuss why \refsubq{metawhy} is a stupid question but \refsubq{why} is even stupider? \label{huh}
            \subquestion! Are \refsubq{huh} and \refsubq{metawhy} both stupider than each other? \label{huh2}
            \subquestion! Please see \refsubq{goto2} for more info. \label{goto}
        \end{subquestionblockA}
    \end{question}

    \begin{question}
        I am just a question.
        \begin{subquestionblock}
            \subquestion! I am a simple subquestion unlike \refsubq{huh2}.
            \subquestion! I am a subquestion (\refsubq{self}) stupid enough to refer to myself\label{self}.
            \subquestion! Please see \refsubq{goto} for even more info. \label{goto2}
        \end{subquestionblock}
    \end{question}
\end{document}
```

Image ::
[image: screenshot]